# how to check two rectangles are touching from left or top or right

Tags: java, intersect

I am using Java awt library.

I am making a simple game where I have a player and enemy as Rectangles. then I set them bounds so I can use the intersect function on them.

Now I want to check how the player and enemy touch. see attchemnt.

[image]

there are mostly 4 different way player can touch the enemy. see the attachemnt. now if player touch the enemy from top than I was go inside the 'if' statment. but if player touch the enemy from left or right than I want to go inseide 'else' statment. I wrote the code below but it doesnt work. for some reason it always goes in else statment.

I was thinking may be there is another function I can use?

```
    if (player.getBounds().intersects(enemy.getBounds())) {
        if (playerY + playerHeight <= enemy.getY()) {
                 //player touch enemy from top
        } else {
                //player touch enemy from left or right
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be not the best solution but it work for what I want. Thanks

```
if (player.getBounds().intersects(enemy.getBounds())) {
if (y + height <= enemy.getY() + enemy.getHeight() / 2) {        
                 //player touch enemy from top
        } else {
                //player touch enemy from left or right
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creative and helpful

Answer (score 0):

You are checking first the rectangles to see whether they intersect. Intersection is not "touching". It's when they have a common rectangle that is not empty.

So, for example, the following two rectangles do *not* intersect:

```
Rectangle a = new Rectangle( 100,100,200,200);
Rectangle b = new Rectangle( 100,300,200,200);
```

But note that `a.y` (100) + `a.height` (200) is exactly `b.y` (300).

Of course, if `a` is above `b`, say, its `y` is 99, then `a.y` + `a.height` is *less* than `b.y`.

So in all cases where `a.y + a.height <= b.y`, the rectangles **do not intersect**.

Since you only go into that `if` if the rectangles do intersect, you'll always end up in the `else`.

If you want to check if they have a slight overlap from above, you can change your condition to `playerY + playerHeight == enemy.getY() + 1`, or even

```
int playerBottom = playerY + playerHeight;
if ( playerBottom > enemy.getY() && playerBottom <= enemy.getY() + DELTA ) {
   ....
}
```

where `DELTA` is a constant that represents how big an overlap you consider "touching".

If you want to see that they touch without overlapping, you can't use the `intersects` method.